# Starting Django Project with gunicorn: No module named: "myproject"

Tags: django, virtualenv, gunicorn, pythonpath

I am having trouble starting my django project with gunicorn
In order to figure out what's wrong, I created an empty django project to work with:

```
myproject
   - myproject
      - __init.py__
      - asgi.py
      - gunicorn_config.py
      ...
      -wsgi.py
   - hello.py
   - manage.py
```

Inside gunicorn_config.py:

```
# gunicorn_config.py
pythonpath ='/home/mywsl/.virtualenvs/venvname/lib/python3.10'
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = 4
timeout = 60
```

my settings.py file (I didn't write anything):

```
from pathlib import Path
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Then i go into myproject where wsgi.py is located and does `gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py wsgi:application`
This raises the following error:

```
[2023-10-07 23:21:39 -0400] [102667] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mywsl/.virtualenvs/venvname/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/mywsl/.virtualenvs/venvname/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
...
  File "/home/mywsl/.virtualenvs/venvname/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
```

(This is where the import module points to outside virtualenv, i don't know if this is normal)

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
```

(It goes back to where my project is, and start tracing python inside virtualenv)

```
  File "/home/mywsl/Projectname/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/mywsl/.virtualenvs/venvname/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/mywsl/.virtualenvs/venvname/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
 ...
```

(Then it goes out of virtualenv again)

```
  File "/home/mywsl/.virtualenvs/venvname/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'
```

In order to make sure that gunicorn is working, I created a hello.py:

```
def process_request(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello, world!'.encode('utf-8')]
```

I then try running it with `gunicorn hello:process_request --bind 0.0.0.0:8000` and it worked on my local development.

python manage.py runserver also worked, so I am thinking this could be an error in my python configuration, but I have no idea how to line up the paths.
Please tell me if you need me to provide anything, thank you!

Comment: Show us your `settings.py` module.

Comment: Updated settings.py, thank you